# Android Studio - Error while downloading Android SDK tools

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

While installing Android Studio I got the following error at the time of initializing. And could not override with the given option (not accepting input).

Error : "Failed to rename directory C:\AndroidSDK\tools to C:\AndroidSDK\temp\ToolPackage.old01."

I gave installation path to C drive for both Android SDK and Studio.

[image: Android Studio error image]

Any Suggestions?

**Solution:**

Open Android Studio as "Run as administrator"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-opened Android Studio with admin privileges. Right click on Android Studio select "Run as administrator".

Answer (score 0):

I might be stating an obvious one here.

- Do you know if you have write permissions on the C drive?

Answer (score 0):

What have you opened in your explorer? Maybe you are in this directory. That is what i could imagine.